# How to send alert or message from view.py to template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am uploading a .xls file from frontend template to Django. In views.py I'm validating the fields of the .xls file, if all is fine I save the file.

If there is a problem I wish to send a message or alert back to the template with the alert message which specifies what went wrong.

I would prefer if the error msg is shown below the file upload field, however, any js alert or any other way is fine too. Please help. Thanks

Extra: If possible I would like to change a span element in my template. Is it possible to do it from views.py?

(I'm uploading the file using AJAX request.)
I tried using messages but nothing is happening.

In views.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES:
.
--code to verify and save the file or generate error msg--
.
if error != 'false':
        messages.info(request, 'The file you uploaded has the following problem: '+error+'. Please fix it and upload the file again')
```

In template:

```
{% block content %}
  --lot of html--
  .
  --file upload field-- 
  .
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  .
  --lot of html--
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Django's forms upon validation attach all the errors. Catch them with `{{ field.errors }}` next to `{{ field }}` or on the form level with `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`.

Comment: Problem is that I'm not using django forms. I'm directly sending the file from the input field via AJAX.

Comment: You probably haven't set up messaging correctly, read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages

Comment: Show the rest of the view. And how are you passing the returned data back to the page in your Ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.Did it this way:

views.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES:
.
--code to verify and save the file or generate error msg--
.
if error != 'false':
    return JsonResponse({'msg': error)
```

And I'm catching the response in the ajax request I used to send the file:

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: 'foo', 
        type: 'post', 
        data: bar, // sending file here
        contentType: false, 
        processData: false,
        async: true,
        success: function(data){ 
            if(data === null){
                alert('success')
            }else {
                alert(data.msg); // can use JS to display the error near the upload field
            }
        },
    });
```